# .NET 7.0 Session being overwritten

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, session

I have a method that is called after a login form submit, and if the user data has been validated in my database model, then i set up a session for this user.

After  that, i still need to show some of the user data on the page (like his username on the navbar, menus and etc) so i created a class named SessionContext that has the same variables that i stored in the session and then i store the session values in those variables

The issue is, everytime a new user logs in on my app (im hosting it on IIS), any other user that is logged in will have his informations replaced with the info of the new user that has just logged in.

I have absolutely no ideia how to fix this, does anybody have a clue??

This is my authentication method:

```js
public LoginController(SessionContext userContext)
 {
     _userContext = userContext;
 }

public object Authenticate()
{
   object userAthentication = new Authentication().AuthenticateUser(username.ToUpper(), password);
   if (userAthentication is Authentication data && userAthentication is not int)
   {
       HttpContext.Session.SetString("session[status]", "authenticated");
       HttpContext.Session.SetString("session[user-login]", data.user);
       HttpContext.Session.SetString("session[user-fullname]", data.name);
       
       _userContext.Login = data.user;
       _userContext.FullName = data.name;
       return 200;
   }
   else {
    return 500;
   }
}
```

This is the SessionContextClass

```js
public class SessionContext
 {
     public string Login { get; set; }
     public string Fullname { get; set; }
 }
```

This is how i show the user's data on my razor pages (thats the info that's being replaced when a new user logs in)

```html
@inject webAppPortalMedico_PFP.Models.Services.SessionContext session

<h5> Hello @session.Fullname ! </h5>
```

Comment: And how does the SessionContext gets into the controller? Where do you collect the Session data from and fill the SessionContext class with before creating the Controller for a request?

Comment: Hey Ralf, im not sure if i understood your question but the first time that i fill the SessionContext class is after the authentication has been completed, and before that all the variables of this class are empty. I get the session data from the HttpContext.Session and i use those values to fill the SessionContext class. 
Thanks for answering

Comment: You shouldn't use a session to store values that should be in user claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not session been overwritten but your  SessionContext been overwritten

As the [docuemnt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0#session-state) mentioned:

> ASP.NET Core maintains session state by providing a cookie to the
> client that contains a session ID. The cookie session ID:
>
> Is sent to the app with each request. Is used by the app to fetch the
> session data. Session state exhibits the following behaviors:
>
> The session cookie is specific to the browser. Sessions aren't shared
> across browsers.

When it comes to your SessionContext,if you registed it as transient/scoped,the state won't be kept between different requests,and juding from your description(other user that is logged in will have his informations replaced with the info of the new user that has just logged in),you registed it as singleton,which means it would always be the same instance in your app

Why not just call
`@HttpContext.Session.GetString("session[user-fullname]")` in your View?

Also,there's build-in support for [Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) in asp.net core,once you authenticate successfully  in authentication middleware,your could get the user name with the codes:`HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`

Comment: Thats's exactly what was happening, the session values were not being altered but it was actually the values of the variables from the SessionContextClass.

I deleted this class and now when i need to show some data from the session into the HTML, im injecting the IHttpContextAcessor in my razor view directly.

Thanks a lot!