IIS - Windows Authentication Session Problem
I have made a razor pages app that authenticates with Windows authentication. It is deployed to IIS.
It checks database for user role, uses ClaimsTransformer and authorize with attributes. Users are in the same domain.
The problem is; a registered user logins and then another user logins. If the first person refreshes the page, their session turns into the second persons session.
I have activated load user profile in IIS and added Http session to the app.
How can I solve this? Thanks

Are you using a similar code like this case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77319065/net-7-0-session-being-overwritten? Then the class you created may be overwritten, which will cause this to happen.
